# How to communicate with GPS SIM900a without Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, gsm, communication, softwareserial

I am fairly new to Arduino. I was working on a project where I use a GSM SIM900a modem interfaced with an Arduino. The AT commands are sent via the Arduino to the GSM Modem. The problem, however, is that the commands are only sent when I open the Serial Monitor. I have an IR proximity sensor and I would like the AT commands to be sent when the sensor detects an object. I am putting the code for the GSM modem below (I have not yet put in the code for the IR sensor).I want to know how to send the AT commands when the Arduino is hooked up to a battery and not to a PC

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myGsm(7,8);
float temp;
int tempPin = 0;
void setup()
{
 myGsm.begin(9600);  
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 delay(500);

myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
 delay(2000);
 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+CGATT=1");
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();


 myGsm.println("AT+CSTT=\"bsnlnet\",\"\",\"\"");//setting the APN,2nd parameter empty works for all networks 
 delay(5000);
 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println();
 myGsm.println("AT+CIICR");
 delay(6000);
 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+CIFSR"); //init the HTTP request
 delay(2000); 
 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"122.178.80.228\",\"350\"");
 delay(5000);
 printSerialData();
 delay(5000);

 myGsm.println("AT+CIPSEND");
 delay(2000);
 printSerialData();

sendtemp();
delay(3000);
myGsm.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
printSerialData();

myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
delay(1000);
printSerialData();
}

void loop()
{
}


void printSerialData()
{
 while(myGsm.available()!=0)
 Serial.write(myGsm.read());
}

void sendtemp()
{
  temp = analogRead(tempPin);
  temp = temp * 0.48828125;
  Serial.print("TEMPERATURE = ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.print("*C");
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
 myGsm.println(temp);
 delay(3000);
 printSerialData();
 myGsm.write(0x1A);
 delay(3000);
   printSerialData();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I too had the same problem until now. The simple way to fix is just to delay the void setup() before Serial communication begins. Add delay(15000); //15 Seconds so that GSM module boots up and connects to the network. And there is no need of changing any part of code. Hope this helps someone out there like me. :)

Comment: This saved my a*s a few hours before my final year university presentations.